# Image saving as file and not png

Tags: c#, image

I use this code to cut off and save image in proper format, but my images are saving a s "file" and not "png" as I would expect. How can I solve this?

```
Rectangle dueDateRectangle = new Rectangle(symbolBounds.X1, symbolBounds.Y1, symbolBounds.X2 - symbolBounds.X1, symbolBounds.Y2 - symbolBounds.Y1);
PixelFormat format = src.PixelFormat;
Bitmap cloneBitmap = src.Clone(dueDateRectangle,format);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
cloneBitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;
Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
i.Save("character" + counter, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

counter++;
```

Comment: The button you clicked is labeled "Ask Question". I don't see a question here. If you don't ask a question you cannot expect an answer. Please read [ask]

Comment: You have not given the file an extension, how does the system know what it is? Side note in the future explain your problem more, `my images save like file, not like png.` is really unclear. Also provide a [MCVE], you have posted a lot of irrelevant code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the following line:

```
i.Save("character" + counter, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

The second argument to the `Save` method is a file path, either full or relative. Therefore, you need to save your image with an extension, in this case probably `.png`:

```
i.Save("character" + counter + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Side note: `Image`, `Bitmap` and `MemoryStream` all implement `IDisposable` so you should be calling `Dispose` on them, or better yet wrapping them in a `using` statement.